# How do you generate a create users script from an existing MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, sql-scripts

Have inherited a MySQL database that was completely trashed by the latest Windows 10 build update.  The server lost all the user and schema information.

I restored the database back and recreated the users, set all the permissions etc.  Obviously I would like to mitigate against this happening in the future but can see no obvious way from workbench to generate a script to create the users and set the permissions as you would from SQL management studio.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible.

You can execute requests with a batch that is loaded by MySQL with a command from the shell to make what you want done.

I had not tested it myself but I think [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html) could be helpful.

Comment: Not sure this is what I am after - I was looking for SQL workbench to generate the script to create the users and set the permissions for each user.  This link is about executing the SQL once you have it :-)